# VPN to server behind router

Tags: networking, vpn

**Full disclosure - I am both drowning and out of my depth without knowing which way is up.  Completely new to networking and a little bit desperate.**

My ultimate objective is to setup a server such that clients can access Files and a FlexLM licence server.

The server is currently on a domestic LAN behind a plusnet one router (UK ISP).  I have configured windows server 2019 essentials and added VPN features.  I am able to successfully connect via VPN to the server when my client laptop is connected via WiFi to the router.

I have a static IP for my router and (I think) put my server in a DMZ (which as I understand it means that requests which are not specifically handled by the router get sent to the server? but as I say I am out of my depth!).   When I connect via my phones hotspot *I can ping the static IP of my router* but cannot establish a VPN connection to server?  I just dont know how to debug or proceeed from here?

More specifically is there any way of establishing whether my server is available from 'outside'?

If I can establish it is available how do I get the VPN connection to the server working?

Every minutes a school minute :-/

Comment: There are many ways but most like this can cost some serious money. Your question is very vague as a result. Probably do some research on what you need.

Comment: Check if [the port is open](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). Port number will differ depending on the VPN protocol you're using.

Comment: Install Wireshark on your server – you'll be able to see whether the system is actually receiving the packets that your VPN client is supposed to send.

Comment: Yes I have done and learned much already John and am clearly not there (or anywhere like near enough!) yet.  As per your advice I will endeavour to know more.
I am using PPTP so expect (I think?) Port 1723 to be open - which your tool shows it is?

Comment: I am intimidated by Wireshark - will I actually be able to understand it as a newb?

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b3c0ca4f-d3ee-4b76-85e7-58ad23258bf2/vpn-server-behind-router-issues?forum=winserverPN

Comment: Yes - this at least confirms that I need to be able to VPN on LAN before I try that - so I *think* this means my server is 'happy' and ready to VPN.  So my key is to figure out a) if I am getting through router to server (is wireshark my best bet for this?) and b) if I am am I able to get to server figure out why the VPN wont work from 'outside'

Comment: Port 1723 is open from the 'outside' do I need to check any other port for PPTP?

Comment: Soooo. The port 1723 is shown as open on my external static IP.  Good.

When I look at Windows Event Viewer logs I see this

CoId={8EA60326-0D3B-4222-A7BD-5723A0F78AEC}: The user SYSTEM has successfully established a link to the Remote Access Server using the following device:
Server address/Phone Number = XXMy public IPXX
Device = WAN Miniport (PPTP)
Port = VPN4-1
MediaType = VPN.

Comment: Which is great!  But then the next event is 

CoId={8EA60326-0D3B-4222-A7BD-5723A0F78AEC}: The user SYSTEM dialed a connection named Turtlestack External which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 806.

The problem persists if I turn off both firewalls? so I am assuming the issue is my router??